# Sort a string array that contains relative filenames

Tags: java, sorting

Consider the following string array, which is a list of file names with relative path:

```
String[] myArray = { "src\\kop\\cKOP_C.o"
                   , "src\\io\\cIO_S.o"
                   , "src\\io\\com\\cGA_M.o"
                   , "src\\io\\cADC.o"
                   , "src\\io\\cIO_H.o"
                   , "src\\io\\com\\com_m.o"
                   , "src\\io\\tab_s.o"
                   , "src\\kop\\cKOP" };
```

The directory layout is:

```
src\io\cADC.o
src\io\cIO_H.o
src\io\cIO_S.o
src\io\tab_s.o
src\io\com\cGA_M.o
src\io\com\com_m.o
src\kop\cKOP_A.o
src\kop\cKOP_B.o
```

I want to sort this array in java to have a result like this:

```
src\\io\\cADC.o
src\\io\\cIO_H.o
src\\io\\cIO_S.o
src\\io\\tab_s.o
src\\io\\com\\cGA_M.o
src\\io\\com\\com_m.o
src\\kop\\cKOP_A.o
src\\kop\\cKOP_B.o
```

Currently I use Array.Sort(myArray), but the result is like this:

```
src\\io\\cADC.o
src\\io\\cIO_H.o
src\\io\\cIO_S.o
src\\io\\com\\cGA_M.o
src\\io\\com\\com_m.o
src\\io\\tab_s.o
src\\kop\\cKOP_A.o
src\\kop\\cKOP_B.o
```

This is not what I want, because I want to `keep` the directory information, so list first all files within a directory, and if there is a sub-directory within, list the files in the sub-dir afterwards.

I know I have to implement a Comparator() for the array to be sorted as I want, but I cannot figure out the logic behind the compare.

Comment: Use [`Arrays#sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T[],%20java.util.Comparator%29) and provide a `Comparator<String>` that supports what you want/need. To ease the comparison, you can create a `File[]` array and use `Comparator<File>`, note that [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class has more methods to support your sort comparator like `isFile` and `isDirectory`.

Comment: <pedantic>Those are relative, not absolute, paths.</pedantic>

Comment: @Ernest: You are absolutely right about the absolute path :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

```
    Arrays.sort(myArray,new Comparator<String> ()
    {
        public int compare(String a,String b)
        {
            if(a.equals(b)) // same path/filename
                return 0;
            int aBSCount = a.replaceAll("[^\\\\]","").length();
            int bBSCount = b.replaceAll("[^\\\\]","").length();

            if(aBSCount==bBSCount) // same directory depth
                return a.compareTo(b);

            String[] aSplit = a.split("\\\\");
            String[] bSplit = b.split("\\\\");

            int shortest = Math.min(aSplit.length, bSplit.length);

            for(int x = 0;x < shortest;x++)
            {
                if(x==shortest-1)
                    return aBSCount < bBSCount ? -1 : 1;

                if(!(aSplit[x].equals(bSplit[x])))
                    return aSplit[x].compareTo(bSplit[x]);
            }

            return aBSCount < bBSCount ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement `sort`:

```
 Arrays.sort(myArray, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
            arg0 = arg0.toLowerCase();
            arg1 = arg1.toLowerCase();
            return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This sorts like the original  `Array.sort(myArray);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            File f1 = new File(o1);
            File f2 = new File(o2);
            int c1 = f1.getParent().compareTo(f2.getParent());
            if (c1 > 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (c1 < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            return f1.getName().compareTo(f2.getName());
        }
```

Comment: This is working fine!. I had to fine tune this a bit, as there are files as well within the current folder, and for those files `.getParent()` is null.